# Shell script embed multiple image with sendmail

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sendmail, mime

I'm using following script to embed multiple image on a mail using sendmail function.

```
sendmail -t <<EOT
TO: example_to@xyz.com
FROM: example_from@xyz.com
Cc: example_cc@xyz.com
SUBJECT: Phobos Report 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;boundary="XYZ"

--XYZ
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
<img src="cid:part1.06090408.01060107" alt=""><br/>
<img src="cid:part2.06090408.01060107" alt=""><br/>
<img src="cid:part3.06090408.01060107" alt="">
</body>
</html>

--XYZ
Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="rag1.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part1.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="rag1.jpg"

$(base64 rag1.jpg)

--XYZ

Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="rag2.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part2.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="rag2.jpg"

$(base64 rag2.jpg)

--XYZ

Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="rag3.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part3.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="rag3.jpg"

$(base64 rag3.jpg)
--XYZ--
EOT
```

Here only the first image getting embedded. And all the others are failed to get added. Those two images are added as text based attachment. How can I add multiple images on this script?

Answer (score 4):

It is an old question, but I think it deserves an answer anyway.

The problem with your code is that you are putting empty lines between the MIME boundary and the MIME headers of the last two images, as here:

```
--XYZ

Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="rag2.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part2.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="rag2.jpg"
```

This is **not** allowed. You should correct your code and delete those empty  lines in two places, as follows, here:

```
--XYZ
Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="rag2.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part2.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="rag2.jpg"
```

and here:

```
--XYZ
Content-Type: image/jpeg;name="rag3.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part3.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="rag3.jpg"
```

Empty lines are allowed *before* the boundary line, which means that they will be part of the preceding body, where they are *usually* harmless (but I can make up contexts where they wouldn’t be. It’s not your case, however.)

It’s best never to put extra empty lines on either side of MIME boundaries. Of course, this is not about the empty line needed before the first MIME boundary, where it separates the MIME header.

Comment: saved my afternoon... was pulling my hair out over this!

Answer (score 0):

try to do it without line break tag

```
<img src="cid:part1.06090408.01060107" alt="">
<img src="cid:part2.06090408.01060107" alt="">
<img src="cid:part3.06090408.01060107" alt="">
```

tested it myself and it is working fine

Comment: No, deleting `<br/>`’s is not enough and doesn’t work for me.

Comment: @Dario you're right. I tested it now and its NOGO with empty lines between bounday and headers